# Qt Creator: No documentation available

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have installed Qt Creator 4.10.2 on Fedora 31 (KDE), using the standard 'dnf install'.  Everything seems to work fine, except one thing: the documentation.  When I highlight a Qt class (e.g. QApplication) and then press F1, I get the message "No documentation available".  However, when I go to Tools > Options > Help > Documentation, I see six entries:

```
org.qt-project.qtcmake.5132 (auto-detected)
org.qt-project.qtcmake.600
org.qt-project.qtcreator.4102 (auto-detected)
org.qt-project.qtdoc.5132 (auto-detected)
org.qt-project.qtdoc.600
```

I have looked at the other StackOverflow questions relating to this issue, and they don't seem to answer my question.  Does anyone know what I have to do to get the documentation in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are [not alone](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1773329)!
You probably need to install a couple of additional rpms. The `QApplication` class  belongs to the 'Qt Widgets' module, which would appear in your help configuration as:

```
org.qt-project.qtwidgets.5132 (auto-detected)
```

Linux vendors like Fedora usually divide library documentation in several RPM packages. You need to guess which ones you are interested and install them as needed. QtWidgets is probably packaged together with other modules in a qtbase package like [this one](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=18385291) (which is for Qt 5.12.3, but you seem to be developing with 5.13.2). Sorry, I don't have a Fedora installation at hand right now. Please try to [search](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/search) the available RPM packages yourself. Good luck!

I tend to not use the Qt packages provided by the Linux vendors. For me, it is much more convenient to use the [qt online installers](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer). You may install several releases side-by-side on your $HOME and you will get the full documentation and examples for each one. There are newer versions than the ones available on Fedora repositories. You may install v5.14.1 right now and try it on your software.

Comment: I used the Qt online installer, and I now have all the documentation in Qt Creator.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the issue (9/2022) as well and was able to do the following on Redhat 8 to install *all* documentation for qtcreator:

% sudo yum install qt5-doc